# What's wrong with this sorting algorithm? (out of bounds exception)

Tags: java, quicksort

The error is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at QuickSort.partition(QuickSort.java:39)
    at QuickSort.quickSort(QuickSort.java:19)
    at QuickSort.sort(QuickSort.java:13)
    at QuickSortTest.main(QuickSortTest.java:15)
```

I can't figure out why it goes out of bounds here.

```
 if (orig[q] >= orig[q - 1]) {
```

I'm testing this for fun. I know using this kind of pivot probably doesn't do anything. I'm trying to to find the largest value in the array in the interval from this -> original length / sqrt of the original length * log 2 (original length) and then the value which is closest to 33% of that largest value and set that to my pivot. Then quicksort normally.

```
import java.lang.*;

public class QuickSort {
    int[] ary;

    public QuickSort(int[] num) {
        ary = num;
    }

    public int[] sort() {
        int low = 0;
        int high = ary.length - 1;
        quickSort(ary, low, high);
        return ary;
    }

    private void quickSort(int[] orig, int low, int high) {
        int save = partition(orig, low, high);
        if (low < (save - 1)) {
            quickSort(orig, low, (save - 1));
        }
        if (save < high) {
            quickSort(orig, save, high);
        }
    }

    private int partition(int[] orig, int low, int high) {
        int i = low;
        int j = high;
        int temp;
        int large = 0;
        int swapspot = 0;
        int need = orig.length / ((int) (Math.sqrt(ary.length)) * ((int) (Math.log(ary.length) / (Math.log(2)))));
        for (int q = need; q > need / 2 - 1; q--) {
            if (orig[q] >= orig[q - 1]) {
                orig[q] = large;
            } else {
                orig[q - 1] = large;
            }
            if (q == need / 2) {
                int saver = (int) (large * .33);
                for (int h = 0; h < orig.length; h++) {
                    if (orig[h] >= saver) {
                        swapspot = orig[h];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        while (i <= j) {
            while (orig[i] < swapspot) {
                i++;
            }
            while (orig[j] > swapspot) {
                j--;
            }
            if (i <= j) {
                temp = orig[i];
                orig[i] = orig[j];
                orig[j] = temp;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        return i;
    }
}
```

Here is the main method

```
class QuickSortTest{

   public static void main(String[] args){

      int[] num = new int[100];      

      for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
         num[i] = (int)(Math.random()*10000);

      }

      long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();   

      QuickSort quick = new QuickSort(num);
         quick.sort();    

      long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();


      for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++){
         System.out.println(num[i]);  
      }
      System.out.println((finish-begin) + " ms");
   } 
}
```

Comment: what error are you seeing?

Comment: Did you want us to guess what "doesn't compile properly" means?

Comment: Add more information on what the error is and what you think is wrong, or this question is likely to get deleted.

Comment: Did you step through with a debugger to see how low q (or need) goes?

Comment: If you have a new question because of a new problem, then create a new post, instead of changing this question and invalidating the existing answer.

Comment: I see no rep for the user and can't click on their name "user5900690" does that mean they deleted their account? New one on me.

Answer (score 2):

Just by looking at these 2 lines of your question:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
if (orig[q] >= orig[q - 1]) {
```

I can tell you that q is 0, and obviously there's no orig[-1]

Update, added by @kaan yılmaz:

for more explanation(actually it is not needed since the answer is good enough but you are asking the basics of programming)

```
 q=0
```

at the beginning of the loop and then you wanted to assign;

```
 q=-1
```

which is not likely to happen, because your CPU cannot reach oriq[-1] as you cannot count apples like -1,0,1,2...

Comment: Oops. Silly mistake. I've updated it but I still have this problem.

Comment: Are you trying to get me fix your code line by line by adding the next error message in comments? I too throw a "StackOverFlow.com error".

Comment: True, if "need / 2 - 1" can be zero.